# How to parse prase fix number of lines , if keyword matches then show first 2 lines

Tags: bash

I am quite new to bash, but really need help with this,
I am parsing a log file which has same strucutre ,i need to parse every 7 lines, if a keyword "failed" matches then show the first 2 lines, then carry on next 7 lines.

if i try to do manually it will be like this, but then i am limited to keyword
"cat multipath_output | grep -B3   'faulty'  | grep -A1  DGC"

Log file is

```
mpathes (3600601601a003200eca1345cf13ce511) dm-84 DGC,VRAID
size=800G features='0' hwhandler='1 alua' wp=rw
|-+- policy='round-robin 0' prio=0 status=enabled
| |- 0:0:1:147 sdtu  65:704   failed faulty running
| `- 1:0:0:147 sdtx  65:752   failed faulty running
`-+- policy='round-robin 0' prio=0 status=enabled
  |- 1:0:1:147 sdadh 65:816   failed faulty running
  `- 0:0:0:147 sdadi 65:832   failed faulty running
mpathdn (3600601601a00320024631529381ee511) dm-50 DGC,VRAID
size=200G features='0' hwhandler='1 alua' wp=rw
|-+- policy='round-robin 0' prio=0 status=enabled
| |- 0:0:0:114 sdhi  133:128  failed faulty running
| `- 1:0:1:114 sdib  134:176  failed faulty running
`-+- policy='round-robin 0' prio=0 status=enabled
  |- 0:0:1:114 sdqn  132:368  failed faulty running
  `- 1:0:0:114 sdrs  134:352  failed faulty running
mpathf (3600601601a00320078b040c86b38e211) dm-19 DGC,RAID 5
size=60G features='0' hwhandler='1 alua' wp=rw
|-+- policy='round-robin 0' prio=130 status=active
| |- 0:0:1:0   sdim  135:96   active ready  running
| `- 1:0:0:0   sdke  66:288   active ready  running
`-+- policy='round-robin 0' prio=10 status=enabled
  |- 0:0:0:0   sda   8:0      active ready  running
  `- 1:0:1:0   sdj   8:144    active ready  running
matchg (3600601601a003200e2efb15f8442e511) dm-257 DGC,VRAID
size=200G features='0' hwhandler='1 alua' wp=rw
|-+- policy='round-robin 0' prio=0 status=enabled
| |- 0:0:1:205 sdye  128:736  failed faulty running
| `- 1:0:0:205 sdyk  129:576  failed faulty running
`-+- policy='round-robin 0' prio=0 status=enabled
  |- 1:0:1:205 sdaht 128:880  failed faulty running
  `- 0:0:0:205 sdahu 128:896  failed faulty running
```

out put  should be :

```
mpathes (3600601601a003200eca1345cf13ce511) dm-84 DGC,VRAID size=800G features='0' hwhandler='1 alua' wp=rw

mpathdn (3600601601a00320024631529381ee511) dm-50 DGC,VRAID
size=200G features='0' hwhandler='1 alua' wp=rw

matchg (3600601601a003200e2efb15f8442e511) dm-257 DGC,VRAID
size=200G features='0' hwhandler='1 alua' wp=rw

"cat multipath_output | grep -B3   'faulty'  | grep -A1  DGC"

Script :-

FILES="multipath.txt"
for f in $FILES
do
        echo "$f"
        cat $f
        # Logic needs to go here

done
```

Comment: Take a look at agrep and its -d option: https://github.com/Wikinaut/agrep

Comment: please clarify your question. You have two sections labeled "out put". What is the difference between "should be" and "will be"???

Comment: @shellter , they both are Same out put , i just just following the structure , I can get the out put by using ""cat multipath_output | grep -B3   'faulty'  | grep -A1  DGC"" but need to make it more dynamic

Comment: It just confuses your Q. Please delete duplicate information. Good luck.

Comment: Do you have blocks of 8 lines or is `mpathes (3600601601a003200eca1345cf13ce511) dm-84 DGC,VRAID
size=800G features='0' hwhandler='1 alua' wp=rw` only one line ?

Answer (score 0):

If it's ok to do this in awk (from the bash shell, LOL) then the following should work.  I would rewrite the rules a little:

1. The start of a "block" is when the first character is an "m"
2. We want to capture line 1 and line 2 of a block, when any line in
   the block contains the word "faulty"
3. We will display line 1 and line 2, if the previous block was faulty.

As a one-liner:

```
awk '/^m/ {if (fault) {print line1 " " line2} ; line1=$0 ; fault=0} ; /^size/ {line2=$0} ; /faulty/ {fault=1} ; END {if (fault=1) {print line1 " " line2}}' t
```

Or line-by-line

1. /^m/ {if (fault) {print line1 " " line2} ; line1=$0 ; fault=0}
2. /^size/ {line2=$0}
3. /faulty/ {fault=1}
4. END {if (fault) {print line1 " " line2}}

[1]=Grab line1 when the line starts with m.  If there's a fault from the previous block, display line1 and line2.  fault will not be true when we get the first block.

[2]=Grab line2 when the line starts with size.

[3]=If there's a fault in the block, set the flag to true

[4]=Since we display faults at the end of a block, after the last block check if there was a fault.

```
mpathes (3600601601a003200eca1345cf13ce511) dm-84 DGC,VRAID size=800G features='0' hwhandler='1 alua' wp=rw
mpathdn (3600601601a00320024631529381ee511) dm-50 DGC,VRAID size=200G features='0' hwhandler='1 alua' wp=rw
matchg (3600601601a003200e2efb15f8442e511) dm-257 DGC,VRAID size=200G features='0' hwhandler='1 alua' wp=rw
```

Comment: @shellter - there was a bug and I was in the middle of editing, so very possible your comment was right, at least for a minute.  Shellcheck for awk would be awesome! ;-)

Comment: Why not just use the same test of `fault` in the `END` block that you have used elsewhere in your script? Now you are assigning `1` to `fault`. You're likely to get duplicate output because of this. Good luck to all.

Comment: I think my remaining comment is on target, but I have been know to get the wrong end of the stick before ;-)

Comment: Good point about inconsistent checks.  I get confused by the various languages = vs == vs === vs eq ;-)  I added the END block after noticing that the last fault section was missing, so good catch.

Comment: yes, comparisons vs assignments can be a hassle. I saw a demo of `R` and they use `<-` (or is it `->`) for assignments. Much less chance for bugs.

Comment: @IanMcGowan  The out put is only lines which stars with "m"  , line can start with without "m"  if i remove the conditon it does not give the first line.

Comment: I can't upvote this answer with an incorrect check still in place. `fault=1` is not the same as `fault==l` or, more plainly, `if (fault) {...}`. Then I can delete my comments too ;-) Good luck to all.

Comment: @alammd It's slightly more complex to do based on position and counting lines.  Is there something else about the start of a block that's consistent and unique to that line?  In your example they all contain the string "RAID" for example, or have parens "(" or 33-digit hex values.  Would changing /^m/ to /RAID/ work for a quick fix?

Comment: @IanMcGowan  it could be "RAID or VRAID" but it can start with any thing word
sorry for late reply due to late night

Comment: @IanMcGowan  may be we can use keyword "dm"

Comment: You can enter newlines between the single quotes of the `awk` command. I don't like horizontal scrolling when reading the answer or code from a colleague. The line-by-line explanation shows good places to enter newlines.